# Cannot resolve symbol 'get' in Android Studio in Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, listview, android-recyclerview

In the `onBindViewHolder` I get error

> 'cannot resolve symbol 'get'

and also the `getHead` and `getDesc` are not working though I have created public Strings in the `Listitem` class.

My android studio version is 2.3.3,
API level is 22 android 5.1,
Build tool version is  25.0.3.

```
package com.example.kanase.recyclerviewapp;  

import android.content.Context;   
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;   
import android.view.LayoutInflater;  
import android.view.View;  
import android.view.ViewGroup;  
import android.widget.TextView;  

import java.util.List;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<Listitem> listItems;
private Context context;

public MyAdapter(List<Listitem> listItems, Context context) {
    this.listItems = listItems;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.list_item , parent ,false );
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Listitem listitem =new listItems.get(position);
    holder.textViewHead.setText(listItems.getHead());
    holder.textViewDesc.setText(listItems.getDesc());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listItems.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView textViewHead;
    public TextView textViewDesc;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textViewHead =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewHead);
        textViewDesc =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDesc);
    }
}
```

This is Listitem class:

```
package com.example.kanase.recyclerviewapp;

public class Listitem {
    private String head;
    private String desc;

    public Listitem(String head, String desc) {
        this.head = head;
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getHead() {
        return head;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }
}
```

Comment: `new listItems.get` why `new`? `listItems.getHead()` why you want to `getHead` from your listItem**s**?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing to do with the android studio version or api level or build tools version.
You are calling getter on the list itself, not on the individual item in the list. And `Listitem listitem =new listItems.get(position);` you don't have to use `new` keyword to get an item from the list

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Listitem listitem =new listItems.get(position);
        holder.textViewHead.setText(listItems.getHead());
        holder.textViewDesc.setText(listItems.getDesc());

    }
```

Change `onBindViewHolder` to,

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Listitem listitem = listItems.get(position);
        holder.textViewHead.setText(listitem.getHead());
        holder.textViewDesc.setText(listitem.getDesc());

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
 Listitem listitem =new listItems.get(position);
holder.textViewHead.setText(listItems.getHead());
holder.textViewDesc.setText(listItems.getDesc());
```

to

```
holder.textViewHead.setText(listItems.get(position).getHead());
holder.textViewDesc.setText(listItems.get(position).getDesc());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your object

```
Listitem listitem = listItems.get(position);
holder.textViewHead.setText(listitem.getHead());
holder.textViewDesc.setText(listitem.getDesc());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Listitem listitem =new listItems.get(position);
```

Remove the `new`.

```
holder.textViewHead.setText(listItems.getHead());
holder.textViewDesc.setText(listItems.getDesc());
```

This looks like a typo. Use `listItem` instead of `listItems`